# Why does the following sql query result in invalid column name?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement:

```
"INSERT INTO OUTSTANDING(type, orderID) VALUES(data, @ID)";
```

or with "" around the words for extra clarity

```
"INSERT INTO OUTSTANDING(type, orderID) VALUES(\"data\", @ID)";
```

Now if I execute this in my c# code I get an error message:

> SqlException: An unhandled exception of type 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred in System.Data.dll: Additional information: Invalid column name data.

Now I'm left wondering how it's possible for SQL to interpret a string inside of value as a string.

Comment: What's the origin on `data`? Is it a *field*, *binding variable*?

Comment: does your query work if you use it directly on the database?

Comment: Trying to understand what your code is meant to do, I come up with "well, I don't know what `data` is meant to mean here" which is pretty much what the error message says.

Comment: data should be just the string data here but if that's the problem then I can understand what's going on.

Comment: what is datatype in type column, keep in mind now you trying to insert string value. ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

double quotes in SQL-Server are [delimiters for identifiers names](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.105).aspx) and not text deliminters.

using double quotes around `data` you tell the RDBMS that it is the name of an object; use single quotes instead:

```
INSERT INTO OUTSTANDING(type,orderID) VALUES('data',@ID);
```

Comment: it is same answer as M. Nasser Javaid gave

Comment: @Bulat almost. the difference is the explanation and the reference to official documentation of the behaviour

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
"INSERT INTO OUTSTANDING([Type], [OrderID]) VALUES('data', @ID)"
```

Instead of

```
"INSERT INTO OUTSTANDING(type, orderID) VALUES(\"data\", @ID)"
```

Comment: You may also want to put `type` column in square brackets `[]` since it is a key word in sql server